# Rails rspec capybara selector not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I have this integration test using capybara:

```
RSpec.describe 'adding a project', type: :system do
  it 'allows a user to create a project with a tasks' do
    visit new_project_path
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Project Runaway'
    fill_in 'Tasks', with: 'Choose Fabric:3\nMake it Work:5'
    click_on('Create a project')
    visit projects_path
    @project = Project.find_by(name: "Project Runaway")
    expect(page).to have_selector(
      "#project_#{@project.id} > td.name", text: "Project Runaway"
    )
    expect(page).to have_selector(
      "#project_#{@project.id} > td.total-size", text: "8"
    )
  end
end
```

Somehow it can't find the last selector (td.total-size):

```
Failures:

  1) adding a project allows a user to create a project with a tasks
     Failure/Error:
       expect(page).to have_selector(
         "#project_#{@project.id} > td.total-size", text: "8"
       )

       expected to find visible css "#project_1 > td.total-size" with text "8" but there were no matches. Also found "3", which matched the selector but not all filters.



     # ./spec/system/add_project_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

But the test is passed when I comment the last assertion. But failed if I commented the td.name part and left the td.total-size uncommented.

Here is the HTML page:

```
<h1>All Projects</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Project Name</td>
      <td>Total Project Size</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr class="project-row", id="<%= dom_id(project) %>">
      <td class="name"><%= project.name %></td>
      <td class="total-size"><%= project.total_size %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to make sure all the data displayed on the table is right. Anyone has the same experience?

For additional information, I am using:

- Rails 5.2.1
- Ruby 2.5.0
- Rspec 3.7.1
- Capybara 3.11.1

Thanks in advance

**Updated**

```
<body>
    <h1>All Projects</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Project Name</td>
          <td>Total Project Size</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="project-row", id="project_1">
          <td class="name">Project Runaway</td>
          <td class="total-size">8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

This is what the html rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the element you expect to have text content of "8" has text content of "3". That would imply to me that either your app has a bug or that `fill_in 'Tasks', with: 'Choose Fabric:3\nMake it Work:5'` isn't doing what you expect it to.  Pause the test and look at the browser to see what's actually being created and/or look at your `test.log` to see what is being submitted and what elements are actually being created.  Note also that I would expect your test to be pretty flaky because you're not actually waiting for whatever action(s) `click_on('Create a project')` performs.  That means the following `visit` can occur before those actions occur and end up cancelling them. Add an assertion between the click and visit for whatever visual change indicates the project creation has completed

```
click_on('Create a project')
expect(page).to have_text('Project created!') # whatever your app does to indicate successful creation
visit projects_path
```

Comment: Hi I updated my question with rendered html. There is a text 8 under the selector

Comment: @KrisMP Post the `test.log` for the test because the error is clearly telling you the element has "3" rather than "8" - so either the HTML you posted isn't from when the test is run, isn't being merged into the page (if AJAX), or is responding after `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds.  Also confused as to why the  `<tr class="project-row", id="project_1">` has a comma in the middle

Answer (score 0):

You can use element hierarchy for table and its td and tr.
such as

```
#getting text of 1st cell of 2nd row
name = find('#tableId tbody tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(1)').text
if name == "Project Name"
   # do what ever you want to do
else
   # do what ever you want to do
end
```

you can put above code block in while loop to go through each and every cell of table. 
Note: Capybara counter starts with 1 so tr:nth-of-type(2) simply means 2nd row.